# What is the meaning of __markedentry

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, jabref, bibentry

I know this might sound like an entry level question. But can someone explain the proper usage of `__markedentry`? it seems to me that it is some mark up for better across device and platform management of the bibliography?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

unknown fields are ignored by bibtex so applications can add extra fields for their own purposes.  In this case it appears to be the jabref bibtex database managing tool leaving information about entries that have been "marked" in that system.

http://discourse.jabref.org/t/jabref-3-8-2-export-bib-with-ranking-and-specific-color/483