# How to avoid __markedentry being added by JabRef?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, jabref, bibentry

I'm managing my BibTeX files/databases with `git` and JabRef 3.8.2 started adding [__markedentry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380068/what-is-the-meaning-of-markedentry). This requires me to pick patch sets (with `git add -i --patch) from the changes (or having the unnecessary marker included in the commits) instead of being able to add changes instantly.

How can I prevent JabRef from adding this on save? Going through the options I don't see anything that might turn this off.

Comment: The JabRef help mentions a "Write values of special fields as separate fields to BibTeX" setting (https://help.jabref.org/en/SpecialFields). But I can't find that setting anywhere in my version. So maybe that page is outdated. It doesn't mention `__markedentry`. If you don't get an answer here, you may want to ask the developers directly at https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/

Comment: I assume you can simply unmark all entries. Of course then you don't keep the nice colour coding. But JabRef has to save that information somewhere. So you can't have your cake and eat it too.

Comment: With the upcoming restyle of the GUI, the markings will be encoded as groups. More info here: https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/pull/3621